# Cycles render causes dark texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am very new to blender, creating my first 3D model, the donut. When I view it with cycles render it appears very dark, almost non textured. When I view it in object mode or eevee render it looks just fine.

Here are some images of the renders:

Cycles:
[image]

Eevee:
[image]

I'm sure the solution is simple, I am just not very familiar with the software.

EDIT: Here are my nodes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bM3X.jpg

Comment: Can you post the nodes for this material?

Comment: I have updated my post with pictures.

Comment: I was able to achieve a similar state, but I'm not sure it's exactly what you're experiencing, nor do I believe I understand what is happening well enough to post an answer.  Go back to the texture paint tab and make sure your image is displayed.  If something is going wrong with the material, the magic fix is usually to disconnect the bsdf output from the surface input and reconnect it.

Comment: Thanks! Reconnecting the bsdf and surface nodes did the trick!